# Algorithm for Rearrange an Array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have an array:

```
1 1A 2 2A 3 3A 4 4A 5 5A
```

I need to Rearrange it by random, with the condition: 1A must behind 1, 2A behind 2...(does not necessarily like 1 1A)

the expect result after rearrange as below:

```
1 4 2 4A 3 2A 5 1A 5A 3A
```

Help me for best algorithm ( best in speed )

Comment: "Best" in which sense? Time? Memory? Distribution?

Comment: thanks, i mean best in "time"

Comment: Put the dependent elements into different queues, than randomly pick an element from a random queue until all the queues are empty.

Comment: So what is this, a random topological sort?

Comment: i not know what is "a random topological sort" :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try like this:

- groups the elements into different queues, such that all the elements that have some 'order' are in the same queue, e.g. `[[1, 1A], [2, 2A, 2B], [3, 3A], ...]`
- randomly select one of those queues, remove the first element and add it to your result
- repeat until all the queues are empty

In case the partial ordering is more complex, e.g. if some element `a` has to be before `b` and `c`, but there is no partial ordering between `b` and `c` you could probably do the same with a tree or similar.

Also, as pointed out by @vib, in order to ensure uniform distribution of elements in the result, you should pick the different queues with probability proportional to the number of elements remaining in that queue.

Comment: Note that grouping requires mapping/sorting the collection (O(n) space/O(nlogn) time) - it is essentially element distinctness problem.

Comment: @amit I thought the grouping would be O(n) time, provided that the sequence is already sorted (as seems to be the case in the question) and you just have to identify the group each element belongs to.

Comment: @tobias_k this is correct if sequence is indeed already sorted.

Comment: If you want to have something really uniform given the constraints you should not pick the queues uniformly at random but with a probability proportional to their size. Otherwise if you take for instance the case 1 2A 2B 2C .. you would see a one in first position half of the time which is not what you would expect from a random permutation.

Comment: @vib That's a good point. Should not be too hard to implement, though. You could just roll a random number from all the numbers and then pick the first element from the queue that number belongs to.

Comment: @tobias_k Exactly. Or you can generate a number between 0 and 1 and infer the queue you need to pick from it. Your approach is good with many small queues, mine better with few large queues.

Answer (score 2):

- Shuffle the array ([Fisher yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle))
- For each x,xA pair - if x is after xA, switch them. This can be done by creating a `map:Element->Index` in `O(n)` for all elements in the array.

Total complexity: `O(n)` (time) average case

Output is guaranteed to be randomly uniformly shuffle, from correctness of fisher-yates.

Pseudo-code:

```
array = shuffle(array)
map = new map
for each element e in array with index i:
    map.add(e,i)
for each element e in the array:
   if e is "x" (not "xA"):
       i = map.get(e)
       j = map.get(xA)
       if j<i:
         swap(arr,i,j)
```

- If there are more than only 2 (x,xA,xB,...) - you can list them all and sort in the main loop, in a similar way.

Comment: thanks you, but i think the tobias 's solution is good and easy for me

Comment: is the "Random pick" algorithm faster than the "shuffle" algorithm?